# I need to display the row values in different column if they repeated for same person id

Tags: mysql, sql

Right now i have the output like this but i need the output in different manner

```
Peron_id  Diagnosis1 doagnosis2 diagnosis3 diagnosis4 
 1         fever
 2         fever
 2         backpain
 2         UTI
```

I need the output like this

```
Peron_id  Diagnosis1 doagnosis2 diagnosis3 diagnosis4 
 1         fever
 2         fever     backpain    UTI
```

Please help me on this.

My framed the complete query now and its showing some error(operand should contain 1 column(s).I paste the query below.please help me

```
SELECT
    visits.id as VisitId,
    visits.person_id as MemberId,
    dept.name as Specialty,
    visits.date as VisitDate,
    visits.followup_to_visit_id as FollowToVisitID,
    visits.chief_complaint as ChiefComplaint1,
    visits.chief_complaint_2 as ChiefComplaint2,
    visits.chief_complaint_3 as ChiefComplaint3,
    visits.valid_state as ValidStatus,
    visits.clinic_type as ClinicType,
    visits.illness_duration as IllnessDuration,
    vitals.temperature_f as Temp,
    vitals.pulse as Pulse,
    vitals.respiratory_rate as RespRate,
    vitals.bp_systolic as BPSystolic,
    vitals.bp_diastolic as BPDiastolic,
    vitals.height_cm as HeightCms,
    vitals.weight_kg as WeightKgs,
    vitals.waist_cm as WaistCms,
    vitals.hip_cm as HipCms,
    referral.referred_to_provider as ReferredOut,
    visits.provider_id as DoctorId,
    prov.full_name as DoctorName,
    prov.registration_number as DoctorRegNum,
    prov.qualification as DoctorQual,
    provloc.name as VisitUphc,
    tk.name as VisitUlb,
    districts.name as VisitDistrict,
    "TN" as VisitState,
    provloc.cachment_code as VisitCatchment,
    visits.entry_date as VisitEntryDate,
    (visits.end_time - visits.begin_time) as VisitEntryTimeTaken,
    visits.created_date as VisitCreateDt,
    visits.last_modified_date as VisitLastModDt,
(Select visit_id,
max(case when i=1 then diagnosis end)as provisional_diagnosis_1,
max(case when i=2 then diagnosis end)as provisional_diagnosis_2,
max(case when i=3 then diagnosis end)as provisional_diagnosis_3,
max(case when i=4 then diagnosis end)as provisional_diagnosis_4
from
(   
select visit_id, diagnosis as diagnosis,
        @i :=IF(@iter=visit_id,@i+1,1)as i,
        @iter :=visit_id
    from  visit_diagnosis_entries v1 
    join (select @iter :=0) v2
      ) vv)
FROM 
visits
    LEFT JOIN visit_vitals vitals ON vitals.visit_id = visits.id 
    LEFT JOIN visit_referral_entries referral ON referral.visit_id = visits.id
    LEFT JOIN visit_diagnosis_entries diag ON diag.visit_id = visits.id 
    INNER JOIN providers prov ON prov.id = visits.provider_id 
    INNER JOIN provider_locations provloc ON provloc.id = visits.provider_location_id 
    INNER JOIN talukas tk ON tk.id = provloc.taluka_id  
    INNER JOIN districts ON districts.id = provloc.district_id 
    INNER JOIN departments dept ON dept.id = visits.department_id limit 5;
```

Previously i explained with one table and now  i need all the columns and additionally with these columns.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array).

Answer (score 2):

If separated columns are not mandatory instead of separated columns in mysql you could try using `group_concat` to get the result in the same row

```
 select person_id, group_concat(Diagnosis1) as diagnosis 
 from my_table  
 group by person_id
```

Comment: I'm upvoting, because I think this might be more useful for the OP.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then we can try a pivot query with the help of `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Peron_id ORDER BY Diagnosis) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    Peron_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN Diagnosis END) AS Diagnosis1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN Diagnosis END) AS Diagnosis2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN Diagnosis END) AS Diagnosis3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN Diagnosis END) AS Diagnosis4
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    Peron_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `conditional aggregation` with `iteration` within the subquery as:

```
select Person_ID,
       max(case when i = 1 then Diagnosis end) as Diagnosis1,
       max(case when i = 2 then Diagnosis end) as Diagnosis2,
       max(case when i = 3 then Diagnosis end) as Diagnosis3
  from 
  ( 
   select t.Person_ID, t.Diagnosis1 as Diagnosis, 
          @i := IF(@iter = Person_ID, @i + 1, 1) as i,
          @iter := Person_ID
     from tab t
     join (select @iter := null,@i:=0) t2
  ) tt 
group by Person_ID;

+-----------+------------+-------------+------------+
| Person_ID | Diagnosis1 |  Diagnosis2 | Diagnosis3 |
+-----------+------------+-------------+------------+
| 1         | fever      |             |            |
| 2         | fever      | backpain    | UTI        |
+-----------+------------+-------------+------------+
```

This method even works for former versions.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=19ed1561e9b0ec932544ad3586ee500e)</kbd>

**Edit** *( thanks to @GordonLinoff ):* Indeed,above method gives all three diagnosis columns,there's a uncertainity about the order of presence among them. So,I think you need one more column such as `Diag_order`.In this case,you'd better to use this below instead of the above one:

```
select Person_ID,
       max(case when Diag_order = 1 then Diagnosis1 end) as Diagnosis1,
       max(case when Diag_order = 2 then Diagnosis1 end) as Diagnosis2,
       max(case when Diag_order = 3 then Diagnosis1 end) as Diagnosis3
  from tab t
 group by Person_ID;

+-----------+------------+-------------+------------+
| Person_ID | Diagnosis1 |  Diagnosis2 | Diagnosis3 |
+-----------+------------+-------------+------------+
| 1         | fever      |             |            |
| 2         | fever      | backpain    | UTI        |
+-----------+------------+-------------+------------+
```

Comment: MySQL explicitly states that the order of evaluation of expressions in a `SELECT` is not guaranteed.  This query relies on the order of evaluation, so I would strongly discourage this approach.